# What is the Honor of Kalos used for?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

At the end of Pokemon X and Pokemon Y, professor Sycamore gives the player an item called the *Honor of Kalos*. Does this item serve a purpose, or is it just a trophy item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point, barring any events or possible DLC, there are no purposes for the Honor of Kalos other than proof that you've defeated the Elite Four.

Comment: I thought the Honor of Kalos was for defeating Lysandre? Sure, you only get it after defeating the Elite Four, but...

Answer (score -1):

The Honor of Kalos is awarded to the player and his friends for saving the Kalos Region at great personal risk. Its basically the real world equivalent of the Medal for Valor which is awarded to a U.S. private citizen when they risk their lives to protect the life of a government official. Most notably the President of the United States or Secretary of Defence.